# How to cover @SneakyThrows annotation by mock tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, lombok

I want to cover by mock test (I use Unit 5) `@SneakyThrows` annotation in one method which looks like:

```
@Override
@SneakyThrows
public String getLocalHostName() {
    return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
    }
```

But all my tryouts are not successful. I've tried to write something like

```
@Test
void testGetLocalHostName_exception() {
    assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> repository.getLocalHostName());
}
```

But it did not cover this annotation.
My mock test btw for the successful case is the following:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyRepositoryImplTest {

    @Mock(lenient = true)
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Mock(lenient = true)
    private InetAddress mockInetAddress;

    @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    private MyRepository repository;

    @Test
    void testGetLocalHostName() {
        var expectedHostname = "mock-hostname";
        Mockito.when(mockInetAddress.getHostName()).thenReturn(expectedHostname);
    
        MyRepository repository = new MyRepository(jdbcTemplate) {
            @Override
            public String getLocalHostName() {
                return mockInetAddress.getHostName();
            }
        };
        assertThat(repository.getLocalHostName()).isEqualTo(expectedHostname);
    }
}
```

Can you help me please to cover this line by test?

Comment: Don't show code that is working, show code that isn't! You're never throwing an exception, so of course `assertThrows` fails. How would you test this code if it wasn't using `@SneakyThrows` but a conventional `throws` declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to test it, you need to make your mock throw some exception when `getLocalHostName` is called:

```
Mockito.when(mockInetAddress.getHostName()).thenThrow(new RuntimeException()); 
// use here the actual exception that will occur in your production code

MyRepository repository = new MyRepository(jdbcTemplate) {
    @Override
    public String getLocalHostName() {
        return mockInetAddress.getHostName();
    }
};

assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> repository.getLocalHostName());
```

Additionally, you can use Assertj for testing exceptions: https://github.com/assertj/assertj. For instance, you can check the exception message:

```
//Assertions from package org.assertj.core.api
Assertions.assertThatThrownBy(() -> repository.getLocalHostName())
        .isInstanceOf(UnknownHostException.class)
        .hasMessageContaining("my custom error message");
```

Comment: thanks! potentially, this code can throw an exception 'UnknownHostException' through standard realisation of 'public static InetAddress getLocalHost() throws UnknownHostException {' but if I try to replace you exceptions by 'UnknownHostException' test did not work

Comment: failing with what error? by the way, you can use assetj for testing exceptions. they have some nic features for it. i have updated my reply with an example

Comment: with error: 'org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Checked exception is invalid for this method!
Invalid: java.net.UnknownHostException'
and your refactored version too

Comment: oh, isee. it's because you have the @SneakyThrows there. In other words, that method does not throw any checked exception and you cannot use mockito to make the mock throw one. You.ll have to use runtime exceptions in this case.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. But with Runtime exception my @SneakyThrows does not cover and decrease my overall coverage. Are there any ways to cover it?

Comment: If you want to cover it with tests, you should mock one level deeper. In other words, you are now testing the `repository`, but the annotation is in `mockInetAddress`. Hope my answers were helpful - if so, I would appreciate an upvote :)